# One independent variable causes the other independent variable in regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, predictor, confounding

I´m investigating how the initial fluid in the retina is related to the visual acuity change over the treatment. Basically, I have three variables: the fluid inside the retina just before treatment began (X1), the visual acuity before treatment (X2) and the visual acuity change at 12 months of treatment (X3).

The dependent variable is X3 which is negatively correlated with X2, i.e, lower visual acuity before treatment implies a bigger (positive) change at 12 months. Additionally, X1 is negatively correlated with X2, i.e, more fluid before treatment implies lower visual acuity before treatment.

When I regress separately both independent variables (X1 and X2), I obtain a positive correlation between X3 and X1 (more fluid before treatment more change) and a negative correlation between X3 and X2 (as I explained previously). But when I include both variables the positive correlation between X3 and X1 turns out negative (more fluid less change).

The problem is that X1 is causing X2: more fluid in the retina is causing a poorer visual acuity before treatment. Therefore, ¿could X2 be assuming the effect of X1 and somewhat distorting the estimate of X1? Since I believe X2 is a mediator, ¿would be better to eliminate X2 from the regression?

Comment: Assuming you are interested in the causal effect of X1 on X3, the correct approach is to regress X3 on X1 alone. Including X2 in the regression is effectively conditioning on X2, which closes off the causal effect of X1 on X3 that is mediated through X2. There are some additional analyses that you can do in the mediator scenario; see Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer for more details.